# remove / add files dynamically to upload field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this input field for file upload:

```
<input onchange="getFiles()" type="file" name='files[]' id="customFile" multiple />
```

On click I can seelct multiple files for upload.
Onchange the function getFiles starts:

```
function getFiles() {
   console.log( $('#customFile').get(0).files )
}
```

which shows me this result:

[image]

This are my two example files.
But If I forgot a file for upload I would be able to add this file with a new upload process. Problem is, if I click again on my upload field and select the forgotten file, it will override the other 2 selected files bevor.

In my "FileList" will only be the last selected.
Is there a way to add one file instead to select all 3 files again for upload?

Comment: Using a `<input type=file>`... no, you're "stuck" with how the UI is built into the browser.  You can add a "manager" which stores the files as you add them then uploads them all.  There's various ways to do this, but I'd probably start with a 3rd party plugin like dropzone.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to save previously uploaded files in local array and push to it inside "getFiles" event handler. Something like this:

```
const uploadedFiles = [];
function getFiles() {
  uploadedFiles.push(...$('#customFile').get(0).files);
}
```

It might also be a good idea to refer to file input using "this" con